# Typescript - Copy function not work with returned value

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, api, copy

I'm facing a problem with copy function and returned value of jquery function.

My main requirement is copying the value of returned short link that generated by bitly API.

Here what i use to copy and short the long URL.

```
copy(textToCopy){
    var dummy = document.createElement("input");
    document.body.appendChild(dummy);
    dummy.setAttribute("id", "dummy_id");
    dummy.setAttribute("value", textToCopy);
    dummy.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(dummy);
    alert("Copied to the clipboard");
}

getShortUrl(url):Promise<any>{
    return new Promise((response)=>{
        let access_token="xxxxxxx";
        $.get("https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token="+access_token+"&longUrl="+encodeURIComponent(url), data=>{
            response(data);
        })
    })
}
```

And here what i wrote to use the functions

```
let longURL = "xxxx";
this.copy(longURL); //for test - copy function works fine
this.getShortUrl(longURL).then(linkData=>{
     console.log(linkData); //JSON
     this.copy(linkData.data.url); //nothing happen here
 })
```

Comment: Maybe bind this to thenable function

Comment: You need have trigger event click it will work. you can refer it: https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/issues/270

Comment: @sonpham i checked all possible solutions but nothing work.. its such as the returned value is not as string to copy it to clipboard .. i need help :(

Comment: @AliH: It only supports when you have a button copy in html and action event click it. I can not find a solution for you either

Comment: @AliH: you can change design and show a button copy when user will click button and copy data.